# Как отличить причастие от прилагательного?

Tags: прилагательные, причастия

В [Викисловаре](https://ru.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9) написано, что слово ***"профилирующий"*** может быть причастием или прилагательным. А как их отличить?

> На первом курсе у меня будут три ***профилирующие*** дисциплины: математика, логика и информатика.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146896/discussion-on-question-by-------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Comment: @Aer  Хорошее было обсуждение. Правда, зачем удалять? У нас и так не очень активный форум (или как это назвать). Постоянных участников очень мало!

Comment: Я уважаю правила сайта и по возможности придерживаюсь их. Но есть активные темы, где желательна наглядность обсуждения, особенно если в нем участвуют несколько человек (формат чата для этого неудобен).  Мы должны вписываться в правила, но и в правилах надо учитывать особенности дискуссии. И желательно, чтобы они способствовали активности участников.

Comment: @Sharon вы можете продолжать обсуждение сколь угодно долго в чате. О функции комментариев можно прочитать здесь: https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я просто хотела сказать, что чат неудобен для обсуждения темы несколькими людьми. В этом случае информация от разных участников приходит быстро, так что трудно следить за тем,что говорится и кем говорится.  Поэтому практически такой формат не используется. Чат удобен для диалога, и такой разговор действительно надо вести там. С другой стороны, правила есть правила...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Профилирующий*** – это причастие  или прилагательное в сочетании «профилирующая дисциплина»?
Попробуем ответить на этот вопрос.

Дисциплина придает профиль?  Да, это **профилирующая** дисциплина.

Но это форма **действительного** причастия настоящего времени. Однако дисциплина  не может совершать **активное** действие, да еще в настоящем времени. Поэтому причастие **переходит в прилагательное** и становится синонимом для слова ***«профильный»*** (от сущ. ***профиль***): профилирующая дисциплина и профильная дисциплина.

А **причастие** «профилирующий» соответствует "производственному" значению глагола «профилировать»: ***профилирующий станок***. Впрочем, прилагательное «профильный» тоже может быть связано с производством: ***профильный лист***.

**P. S.** Значения слов ***профилировать, профиль и профильный*** предварительно проверено по нескольким словарям.

При ответе учтены **все мнения,** высказанные в ходе дискуссии. Ответ получился коротким, а обсуждение было долгим. **Спасибо всем его участникам!**

Comment: Не очень нравится такая формулировка: "дисциплина не может совершать активное действие". Ну как же? Вдохновляющая математика, бодрящая живопись.

Comment: Математика вдохновляет. живопись бодрит? Да, мы так говорим: Живопись, математика воздействуют на эмоции, вызывают чувство вдохновения, бодрости.  Но может ли та же математика профилировать факультет в вузе. В толковом словаре Кузнецова у глагола профилировать стоит пометка спец. лексика, поэтому активное действие здесь под вопросом. Также тот факт, что "профилирующий" является синонимом прилагательного "профильный" подтверждает переход причастия в прилагательное. Сравним с парой слов: рассеянные туч-рассеянный человек для страдательных причастий. Также: вызывающий тон, гнетущее чувство.

Comment: Таким образом, значительная часть причастий подвергается временной адъективации, то есть в одних условиях выступает в качестве причастий, а в других – в качестве прилагательных. Основной метод проверки – замена синонимом из числа прилагательных.

Comment: Да, в этом, конечно, вы правы. Мне очень странным показался тот факт, что у  "профилировать" нет значения "создание определенного вектора развития"; для меня вопрос, почему его прилагательному  передали. Возможно, существенное влияние оказало наличие "профильного".

Comment: Замена синонимом – это подтверждение качественного признака, а не признака по действию.  Но сомнений было много...

Comment: Ну тут, опять же, как я уже ранее говорил, не все так однозначно. Метод  замены не всегда работает, часто он основан на переосмыслении (приводил уже тут пример со словом "сломанный"). Я несколько лет назад отправлял вопрос в ИРЯ РАН. Был такой ответ:

Comment: Выделяют два основных случая адъективации причастий.
1) Более или менее однозначно переход причастия в прилагательное признается в тех случаях, когда в результате адъективации у причастий происходит развитие переносных лексических значений, характерных для качественных прилагательных (ср.: блестящий талант). В этом случае происходит семантический отрыв адъективированного причастия от соответствующего глагола.
2)

Comment: 2) Однако если адъективация причастий основывается на переосмыслении значений вида, времени и залога без утраты связи с ними, то вопрос об их переходе в другой лексико-грамматический класс слов является спорным.
Так, для причастий прошедшего времени совершенного вида характерно обозначение состояния, являющегося результатом предшествующего действия, а для действительных и страдательных причастий настоящего времени — обозначение способности выполнять действие или подвергаться воздействию извне (ср.: освещенные окна, вьющееся растение). Частеречная принадлежность (2) типа под вопросом.

Comment: Да, значение именно переносное, уходим от действия в сторону признака. Есть синоним среди прилагательных – значит, уже ушли. У меня есть учебник по морфологии, там перечислены признаки перехода (5 признаков названо). Интересный признак – утрата парного причастия: извиняющийся – извинявшийся.

Comment: Реальное действие: профилирующий станок или  профилирующий резец. Он уж точно создает профиль в реальном времени. (Можно сказать: профилировавший  нужный профиль резец сломался.) Можно представить, как математика вдохновляет человека, воздействует на его эмоции. и это тоже будет реальное действие в определенный момент времени. Но нельзя сказать, что математика профилирует  факультет сейчас, в настоящий момент. Поэтому наличие синонима – это просто показатель перехода, но главная причина – утрата реальности действия.

Answer (score 3):

**Материал из комментариев**

**Ответ ИРЯ РАН**

Выделяют **два основных случая** адъективации причастий.

1. Более или менее однозначно переход причастия в прилагательное признается в тех случаях, когда в результате адъективации у причастий происходит развитие **переносных лексических значений**, характерных для **качественных** прилагательных (ср.: блестящий талант). В этом случае происходит **семантический отрыв** адъективированного причастия от соответствующего глагола.
2. Однако если адъективация причастий основывается **на переосмыслении** значений вида, времени и залога **без утраты связи с ними**, то вопрос об их переходе в другой лексико-грамматический класс слов является **спорным.** Так, для причастий прошедшего времени совершенного вида характерно обозначение состояния, являющегося результатом **предшествующего действия**, а для действительных и страдательных причастий настоящего времени — обозначение **способности выполнять действие** или подвергаться воздействию извне (ср.: освещенные окна, вьющееся растение).*

**Комментарии**

*Не очень нравится такая формулировка: "дисциплина не может совершать активное действие". Ну как же? Вдохновляющая математика, бодрящая живопись.*

Математика вдохновляет, живопись бодрит? Да, мы так говорим:  Живопись, математика воздействуют на эмоции, вызывают чувство вдохновения, бодрости. Но может ли та же математика **профилировать факультет в вузе**?

В толковом словаре Кузнецова у глагола «профилировать» стоит пометка спец. лексика, поэтому **активное действие здесь под вопросом.** Также тот факт, что "профилирующий" является синонимом прилагательного "профильный" подтверждает переход причастия в прилагательное. Сравним с парой слов: *рассеянные туч – рассеянный человек* для страдательных причастий. Также: *вызывающий тон, гнетущее чувство.*

Таким образом, значительная часть причастий подвергается **временной адъективации,** то есть в одних условиях выступает в качестве причастий, а в других – в качестве прилагательных. Основной **метод проверки** – замена синонимом из числа прилагательных.

*Мне очень странным показался тот факт, что у "профилировать" нет значения "создание определенного вектора развития"; для меня вопрос, почему его прилагательному передали. Возможно, существенное влияние оказало наличие "профильного".*

Замена синонимом – это **подтверждение качественного признака**, а не признака по действию. Но сомнений было много... Здесь значение именно **переносное**, уходим от действия в сторону признака. Есть синоним среди прилагательных – значит, уже ушли.

У меня есть учебник по морфологии, там перечислены признаки перехода (5 признаков названо). Интересный признак – **утрата парного причастия:** *извиняющийся – извинившийся*.

Реальное действие: ***профилирующий станок или профилирующий резец.*** Он уж точно создает профиль в реальном времени. (Можно сказать: профилировавший нужный профиль резец сломался.) Можно представить, как математика вдохновляет человека, воздействует на его эмоции, и это тоже будет **реальное действие** в определенный момент времени.

Но нельзя сказать, что **математика профилирует** факультет сейчас, в настоящий момент. Поэтому наличие синонима – это просто **показатель** перехода, но **главная причина** – утрата реальности действия.

Если рассматривать фразу «*Профилирующие дисциплины – дисциплины, которые профилируют вуз*» по РАН, то это вопрос **о способности** выполнять такое действие в реальном времени.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ** от 30.06.2023г.

**Признаки адъективации причастий** (по учебнику для вузов  Г.Ф. Рахимкуловой  «Морфология современного русского языка»)

**1. Утрата зависимых слов**: жареный на масле картофель (прич.) — жареный картофель (прил.).

**2. Употребление в переносном значении**: извиняющаяся девушка (прич.)  — извиняющая  улыбка (прил.).

**3. Вхождение в состав терминологического сочетания:** пишущая машинка — это машинка, приспособленная для письма, а не та, которая пишет.

**4. Утрата парного причастия:** извиняющаяся девушка — извинившаяся девушка.

**5. Способность образовывать** степени сравнения, краткую форму, определительное наречие: дискуссия стала оживленнее,  образованнейший человек, подробности потрясающи, подействовало ошеломляюще.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146959/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon-----); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146960/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon-----); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 1):

Я не могу придумать звучащую фразу, когда *профилирующий* - это прилагательное, да и когда причастие тоже.

Профилирующая дисциплина - это как предикативное название, условие дисциплины - профилирование(profiling)? Но тогда такая дисциплина называется "профильной" - обычное русское прилагательное без всяких -ющ-. Также у меня есть сомнение вообще в смысле словосочетания "профилирующая дисциплина", потому что профилирующий - это образующий профиль, оформляющий. А дисциплина - это комплекс принципов действия/поведения, то есть уже основа формы чего-то. В этом смысле оформляющий принципы действия, это даже хуже, чем оформляющий форму, а оформляющий основу формы - бред бредовый. Или что-то профилируется, или это принцип - дисциплина. Такая же логика рассуждения справедлива для "профилирующий предмет".

На Нацкорпусе единичные случаи употребления слова *профилирующий*. В то время как **профильный** - вполне себе ходовое. Так что *профилирующий*, скорее всего, кривая форма слова профильный, я бы её не употреблял ввиду наличия внятного аналога.

Станок же - [**профилировочный**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc_geolog/4171/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9), а не профилирующий.

Профильный - изначально, слово относящееся к портрету человека в профиль, либо это была профильная линия рисунка - контур, а значение технического термина оно получило только в 1970 судя по Нацкорпусу.

Хотя у наших братьев есть профілівний станок - профилирующий станок)?

Ну и, если очень уж хочется ввинтить профилирующий (shape forming machine - профиль формирующий станок / станок формирующий профиль), то - станок, профилирующий брус, но по-русский лучше **станок для профилирования бруса**. Если есть возможность убрать разночтения, что конкретно, что профилирует - то нужно этим пользоваться, а не создавать языковую путаницу.

То есть корректная терминологическая фраза с "причастием" звучит как: *станок* (определяемое слово) *для* (предлог целевого воздействия на) *профилирования* (отглагольное существительное, предикатив, оно же (в паре с предлогом)  - сказуемое) *бруса* (то, что конкретно является целью воздействия). Данная фраза, как собственно и *профильный предмет/ВУЗ/дисциплина* - не создают никаких разночтений.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146952/discussion-on-answer-by------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.